# Select rows with same value in different columns or null . There are multiple rows with same id

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have  a table like below:

[image]

I have to remove the id with different value in MS1,MS2,MS3,MS4 and MS5.NuLL value is not checking.My final o/p should be with same value in MS1,MS2,MS3,MS4 and MS5.

My o/p would be like below:

[image]

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: i am using sql server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 select outerInstance.* from t outerInstance where outerInstance.id not in 
   (select innerInstance.id from t innerInstance where
    isnull(innerInstance.ms1,'null') not in (isnull(innerInstance.ms2,innerInstance.ms1),'null') or
    isnull(innerInstance.ms1,'null') not in (isnull(innerInstance.ms3,innerInstance.ms1),'null') or
    isnull(innerInstance.ms1,'null') not in (isnull(innerInstance.ms4,innerInstance.ms1),'null') or
    isnull(innerInstance.ms1,'null') not in (isnull(innerInstance.ms5,innerInstance.ms1),'null') or 
    isnull(innerInstance.ms2,'null') not in (isnull(innerInstance.ms3,innerInstance.ms2),'null') or
    isnull(innerInstance.ms2,'null') not in (isnull(innerInstance.ms4,innerInstance.ms2),'null') or
    isnull(innerInstance.ms2,'null') not in (isnull(innerInstance.ms5,innerInstance.ms2),'null') or
    isnull(innerInstance.ms3,'null') not in (isnull(innerInstance.ms4,innerInstance.ms3),'null') or
    isnull(innerInstance.ms3,'null') not in (isnull(innerInstance.ms5,innerInstance.ms3),'null') or
    isnull(innerInstance.ms4,'null') not in (isnull(innerInstance.ms5,innerInstance.ms4),'null')) ;
```

Though I have never worked on SQL Server, but give a try to this..it may help you

Comment: Thanks.This query is almost working..But in some scenario, for eg: id   lineid         ms1             ms2  
5413 1 391 408
5413 2    391          NULL

Comment: sorry.i could not continue the above comment..This query is almost working..But in some scenario, for eg ;     same id,but first record has different ms numbers.Then I want to remove the second record also with the same id.But this case ,i am getting the second row.first row is eliminating  
5413 1 391         408
5413 2    391          NULL

Comment: I have edited the query in my answer, you can try that

Comment: Thanks for the query.I will try it.

Comment: I tried.But this query is not working for the above scenario what i mentioned.Bcz,the same id in the main selection also.If any of the record with same id has different msn no,I don't want to show all the records with that same id.

Comment: Can you run the subquery independently and tell me if returns those ids which have different ms no or not?

Comment: I tried this query and checked in some scenarios with different msn combinations.almost working fine.very few different msn records are coming.But I used another query to find out any different msn coming after running  your query.I hope i can go ahead with this query..Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the ids that don't match:

```
select id
from t
group by id
having min(ms1) <> max(ms1) or
       min(ms2) <> max(ms2) or
       min(ms3) <> max(ms3) or
       min(ms4) <> max(ms4) or
       min(ms5) <> max(ms5) ;
```

You can get the rest of the ids in other ways, say `left join`:

```
select t.*
from t left join
     (select id
      from t
      group by id
      having min(ms1) <> max(ms1) or
             min(ms2) <> max(ms2) or
             min(ms3) <> max(ms3) or
             min(ms4) <> max(ms4) or
             min(ms5) <> max(ms5) 
     ) ids
     on t.id = ids.id
where ids.id is null;
```

Comment: I tried to use this query.But still i am getting ids with different values in column.Is there any other way to come to the solution?

Comment: @SGR . . . The first query doesn't return the set of `id`s that have different values?

Comment: I am getting only a few records based on the first query. A few records which has different MS number in the same column.

Comment: @SGR . . . Exactly.  The second query should then return all the rows for the rest of the ids.